# How to store MapReduce result in hierarchically in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I want to perform map-reduce operation on some metric and want to store its result aggregated and time-series.

Storing the aggregated result seems to be very simple, but how can i store the result in time-series fashion i.e. whenever the map-reduce function run's the value at that interval should also be recorded in the result collection.  (i.e. time-series data)

Let's say i have a following result out of my map-reduce aggregation:-

```
> db.result.find()
{ "_id" : { "eventId" : 1}, "value" : { "sum" : 21 } }
{ "_id" : { "eventId" : 2}, "value" : { "sum" : 31 } }
```

I am able to achieve the above very easily with map_reduce aggregation framework.

I want the result to be stored in timeseries as well, like below:-

```
> db.result.find()
    { "_id" : { "eventId" : 1}, "value" : { "sum" : 21, "ts": {1: 15, 2: 4, 3: 2  } } }
    { "_id" : { "eventId" : 2}, "value" : { "sum" : 31, "ts": {1: 12, 2: 12, 3: 7 } } }
```

Now whenever the map-reduce function would run it should update the result collection.

I tried numerous ways to do so, but was unable to succeed in it. Any idea how can i achieve it?

Also, if this could be possible under the same map-reduce function call then that would be great.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want without your attempts at getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The general recommendation for such time series data is to use [pre-aggregated reports](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/).

If that is not possible, first consider using the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) instead of map-reduce. It's faster and easier if your use case allows it.

With both the aggregation pipeline and map-reduce, you can use the results create the desired document. [setOnInsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) may be helpful.

Comment: General recommendation is not possible because i have to calculate data after it has been stored in mongo.

I would have tried and used aggregation pipeline, but then I want the result to be stored somewhere to used for later querying.

That's why i used map-reduce which would run every interval and compute the data and store in other collection, i want to store its time series as well.